# Why is D3DKMTQueryStatistics always returning 0 as RunningTime for the GPU 3D engine node?

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, gpu, direct3d

I have an app that calculates the GPU usage. I want to avoid using the PerformanceCounter API (this one works as expected), because it is too slow at first initialization.

I tried using `D3DKMTQueryStatistics`, and after a lot of investigation I found why my algorithm is not giving accurate results. It seems that the RunningTime for the 3D Engine node always returns 0. I even tested while running a benchmark in FurMark that stress the GPU at 100% but it's still 0.

```
var enumerator = new D3DKMT_ENUMADAPTERS();

D3DKMTEnumAdapters(ref enumerator);

var node = new D3DKMT_QUERYSTATISTICS()
{
   Type = D3DKMT_QUERYSTATISTICS_TYPE.D3DKMT_QUERYSTATISTICS_NODE,
   AdapterLuid = enumerator.Adapters[0].AdapterLuid,
   QueryElement = { QueryNode = { NodeId = 0 } } // 0 is the 3D engine node
};

D3DKMTQueryStatistics(ref node)

var runningTime = node.QueryResult.NodeInformation.GlobalInformation.RunningTime.QuadPart;
```

`runningTime` is always 0, no matter how many times I query it. (all the code is part of a while)

What am I missing?

---

I'm testing this in a simple .NET Core Console App, but I feel like I miss something. There is another node that gives me results, but that one is rarely used by the GPU so it works but partially.

I tried using LibreHardwareMonitor library but with the same inconsistent results.

I also tried to run the app elevated but still returning 0.

I tried OpenHardware Monitor on my PC, and this one reports the usage correctly and it's using LibreHardwareMonitor behind the scenes. So I think I'm missing something. OpenHardwareMonitor is made in C++ tho.